# Minecraft execute if scoreboard value = 0 with command blocks

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I want to make a command block that executes "say Zero pigs alive" when the amount of pigs on the map is zero. I made a pig count with a scoreboard on the side that shows the amount of pigs when I press on the button, but I want a command to be executed when the amount is zero on the scoreboard. Does anyone know how I can do this?

[image: scoreboard screenshot saying "pig 16"]

This is what is looks like, when the 16 is a zero, so no pigs are in the map, it needs to activate the next command block that says "Zero pigs alive"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , this is possible. You would want to do something along the lines of

```
execute if score test pig matches 0 run say Zero pigs alive
```

**But**, you can check if there are no entities alive and say your message all in one command, which would be more efficient. An example would be

````
execute unless entity @e[type=pig] run say Zero pigs alive```
````

Comment: Thank you very much! :)